# Regular expression help for href attribute check

Tags: java, html, regex

I have the below regular expression check for href attribute which checks for protocol, sitename & domain. I need to add a check for "javascript:". Could someone help me on this? I am not able to get it work.

```
(\s)*((ht|)f)tp(s?)://|mailto:)[\p{L}\p{N}\.\#@\$%\+&amp;;:\-_~,\?=/!\(\)]*(\s)*
```

Comment: If you've done any search on this site on this sort of question, you'll invariably see that most recommend avoiding regex for HTML parsing, that instead you should use a better tool, an HTML parser such as JSoup. So,... why not?

Comment: I am validating the content at serverside for cleanhtml, so i can't use the tool. If you have a regex for this, please let know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the first set of your matching parenthesis, just add another "OR" possibility after the mailto. change from:

```
(\s)*((ht|f)tp(s?)://|mailto:)[\p{L}\p{N}\.\#@\$%\+&amp;;:\-_~,\?=/!\(\)]*(\s)*
```

to

```
(\s)*((ht|f)tp(s?)://|mailto:|javascript:)[\p{L}\p{N}\.\#@\$%\+&amp;;:\-_~,\?=/!\(\)]*(\s)*
```

not sure if your regex got messed up while posting here, but your parenthesis around the http/ftp part were a bit messed up